# How to create multiple instances of a dynamic component sequentially?

Tags: angular, subject, angular-dynamic-components

I have a `SystemMessageService` which creates instances of `SystemMessageComponent` using the following method

```
createSystemMessage(message: string, vcr: ViewContainerRef, time: number = 4500, isErrorMessage: boolean = false, isWarningMessage: boolean = false, isSuccessMessage: boolean = false){
    let systemMessageCmpFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(SystemMessageComponent);
    this.hostViewContainerRef = vcr;
    this.hostViewContainerRef.clear();
    this.systemMessageCmpRef = this.hostViewContainerRef.createComponent(systemMessageCmpFactory);
    this.systemMessageCmpRef.instance.message = message;
    this.systemMessageCmpRef.instance.timeUntilDestruction = time;
    this.systemMessageCmpRef.instance.isErrorMessage = isErrorMessage;
    this.systemMessageCmpRef.instance.isWarningMessage = isWarningMessage;
    this.systemMessageCmpRef.instance.isSuccessMessage = isSuccessMessage;
    this.closeSubMsg = this.systemMessageCmpRef.instance.closeMessage.subscribe(() => {
      this.closeSubMsg.unsubscribe();
      this.hostViewContainerRef.clear()
    })
  }
```

Now I have a notifier in `SystemMessageService`,

```
private systemMessageNotifier$: Subject<string> = new Subject();
public systemMessageObs$ = this.systemMessageNotifier$.asObservable();
emitSystemMessage(systemMessage: string){
    this.systemMessageNotifier$.next(systemMessage);
}
```

which informs `app.component.ts` when to display a new system message

```
@ViewChild('systemMessageHost', {read: ViewContainerRef}) systemMessageHost: ViewContainerRef;
  constructor(private systemMessageService: SystemMessagesService){

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.systemMessageService.systemMessageObs$.subscribe(systemMessage => {
      this.systemMessageService.createSystemMessage(systemMessage, this.systemMessageHost, 60*1000*60)
    })
  }
```

but the problem is that messages would overlap if sent sequentially, for example if I call the following in any component

```
this.systemMessageService.emitSystemMessage("Message1");
this.systemMessageService.emitSystemMessage("Message2");
```

I would only show "Message2" but I want to show "Message1" first and if the user closes the component, then "Message2" should be shown afterwards. How would I implement this? The `SystemMessageComponent`can be closed either by timeout or click on a close button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it this way: I use a variable to check whether an instance exists. If it exists I push the next message in an array. When the instance is destroyed, I use a notifier to inform `app.component` that the instance was destroyed so that, if there is another message, the next message can be shown.

```
private systemMessageNotifier$: Subject<SystemMessage> = new Subject();
public systemMessageObs$ = this.systemMessageNotifier$.asObservable();
private sysMsgDestroyedNotifier$: Subject<any> = new Subject();
public systemMessageDestroyed$ = this.sysMsgDestroyedNotifier$.asObservable();

createSystemMessage(message: string, vcr: ViewContainerRef, messageType: SystemMessageType, noTimeOut: boolean = false, timeUntilDestruction: number = 1000*3600){
    let systemMessageCmpFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(SystemMessageComponent);
    this.hostViewContainerRef = vcr;
    this.hostViewContainerRef.clear();
    this.systemMessageCmpRef = this.hostViewContainerRef.createComponent(systemMessageCmpFactory);
    this.systemMessageCmpRef.instance.message = message;
    this.systemMessageCmpRef.instance.timeUntilDestruction = timeUntilDestruction;
    this.systemMessageCmpRef.instance.messageType = messageType;
    this.systemMessageCmpRef.instance.noTimeOut = noTimeOut;
    this.closeSubMsg = this.systemMessageCmpRef.instance.closeMessage.subscribe(() => {
      this.closeSubMsg.unsubscribe();
      this.hostViewContainerRef.clear();
      this.sysMsgDestroyedNotifier$.next();
    })
  }
```

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  delayedSystemMessages = [];
  isSystemMessageComponentActive: boolean = false; 
  @ViewChild('systemMessageHost', {read: ViewContainerRef}) systemMessageHost: ViewContainerRef;
  constructor(private systemMessageService: SystemMessagesService){

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    
    this.systemMessageService.systemMessageDestroyed$.subscribe(() => {
      if(this.delayedSystemMessages.length > 0){
        this.isSystemMessageComponentActive = false;
        let message = this.delayedSystemMessages.shift()
        this.systemMessageService.emitSystemMessage(message);
      }
    })

    this.systemMessageService.systemMessageObs$.subscribe(systemMessage => {
      if(this.isSystemMessageComponentActive){
        this.delayedSystemMessages.push(systemMessage)
        return;
      }
      this.isSystemMessageComponentActive = true;
      this.systemMessageService.createSystemMessage(systemMessage.message, this.systemMessageHost, systemMessage.messageType, systemMessage.noTimeOut, systemMessage.timeUntilDestruction)
    })
  }
}
```